# How to prune sibling blocks?

Tags: database, pruning

Testing some behaviors on a collator, I often end-up with `[] Block import error: State Database error: Too many sibling blocks inserted`

Is there way to remove those siblings from the database ?

Comment: As per my understanding, there is nothing that enables you to drop siblings arbitrarily from db atm, though siblings are pruned when ancestor blocks get finalized so ensuring a small finalization window should prevent these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to revert the siblings is to use `./binary revert ...`
Ex: `polkadot revert --chain=rococo-local 1`

This was not possible for parachain due to how they treat leaves and best blocks (dependant on the relaychain), but has since been fixed (see https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11716)