# How to execute a runtime upgrade that takes more weight than one block can hold

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, parachain-system

I'm trying to execute a runtime upgrade on a running parachain. I'm using the cumulus parachainSystem pallet to do, using the authorize -> enact flow.

My parachain have the contracts pallet, with the standard migration.

The steps I'm doing are the following:

1. I'm just modifying the spec_version, without adding or removing any pallet.
2. Then I run `cargo build --release -p <runtime pkg>` to build the new runtime blob.
3. To execute the authorize_upgrade, I get the smallest file generated by the command above. Which the file name is something like `<runtime pkg>.compact.compressed.wasm`
4. I execute the enact_upgrade call, and here is where the problem starts!

I've got mixed outputs, doing with and without the scheduler pallet.

It outputs this error first:
[image]
And it tries to collate over and over until the error `Import failed: State Database error: Too many sibling blocks inserted` start appearing.
[image]

I've tried using the scheduler already, but I'm probably doing something wrong? How can I properly set the scheduler with the auth -> enact flow, to successfully execute the runtime upgrade in the parachain?

I'm calling using sudo, like this:
[image: authorize_upgrade]

### The steps I'm doing:

The upgraded runtime just have the spec_version increased, no pallets removed/addded.

1. Scheduled a `authorize_upgrade` call, to be executed in n+5 blocks.
2. Waited the execution of the n+5 block.
3. After, scheduled the `enact_authorize`to be executed in n+10.

When the second scheduled call happens, it keeps starting collation until the `too many siblings` error starts popping up.

Is the order right?
Do I need to make a set_code call in the Parachain, before or after the auth/enact?

Comment: To address `Import failed: State Database error: Too many sibling blocks inserted` have a look at https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/how-to-prune-sibling-blocks
This issue is solved by https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your migration is "too long". You may need to try a different migration strategy.

More on this can be found here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/runtime-upgrade/#choose-your-upgrade-approach

Comment: I've already followed those instructions. The only needed calls to execute the parachain upgrade, must be done **only** in the parachainSystem pallet? There is no need to make extra calls on the relay? Or calling a set_code after or between the auth -> enact flow?

Comment: When I'm executing with the scheduler pallet, I run in this sequence:
scheduled a call, auth_upgrade, to block n + 5.
after the block n+5, I then scheduled another call to enact in again, n+5 blocks.
What is the correct order to make those calls?

Comment: The issue is not with the calls. You have them correct. This issue is with the migration. Your migration most likely takes up more than what one block can hold.

Comment: Okay, so how could I use the scheduler pallet to successfully execute the upgrade in more than 1 block. I was thinking that scheduling would resolve the more than 1 block need.

Comment: This may help: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/how-do-i-do-a-mult-block-migration

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and support Bruno! The 5852 you posted is so damn good, I was able to understand de facto the processes. Thanks again, and I was able to execute a runtime upgrade using zombienet.