# ParaChain blocks are not producing and finalising with Relay chain ( when using with custom specs)

Tags: polkadot, relay-chain, parachain-collator, substrate-parachain-template, polkadot-local

Hope you are doing well.

I would need your valuable insights on an issue. Currently I m facing a problem with para-chain(rococo-local) set-up locally with relay chain(rococo-local).

I have setup Relay-chain(release-v0.9.32) with 5 Session keys. Relay-chain is producing blocks and Finalizing and I setup Para-chain(polkadot-v0.9.32) and registered on my Relay chain. Para-chain showing Relay chain's logs but not producing any block.

Anyone please help me how can I resolve this problem. I will be thankful to you.

Parachain's log:
[image]

Relaychain's log [Connected with 5 validators]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The relay you're setting up, are you using custom keys or dev accounts?
- In the parachain log, does it try start collating over and over until errors/warns start appearing? like `too many siblings` or `header not found`?

If that is the case, you might have the same issue I've had in the past.
[How to properly set session keys for Relay and Parachain with custom keys](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/how-to-properly-set-session-keys-for-relay-and-parachain-with-custom-keys?rq=1)

Let me know if that is your case, and if that helped.

Comment: The relay you're setting up, are you using custom keys or dev accounts?
>>> yes. I have replaced with my own keys. using 5 session keys.

Comment: In the parachain log, does it try start collating over and over until errors/warns start appearing? like too many siblings or header not found?

>> yes it also happening.

Comment: I have used own custom keys for Relay chain and different own keys for parachain.

would I have to use same keys for both - Relay chain and parachain ?

Comment: No no, you're probably inserting the keys in the wrong way.  You can use separate keys, there's no reason to use the same keys, actually is the opposite, DO NOT.  Follow the instructions on the link I posted, you need to insert the session keys correctly for the Relay and Parachain. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/how-to-properly-set-session-keys-for-relay-and-parachain-with-custom-keys?rq=1

Comment: yes. It fixed my issue. Actually Problem was - I needed to create an account on relay chain by using any session key mentioned in para-chain spec and transferred balance in that new Account and use the same account to create the ParaID. so that they can do handshake. I had missed that and was using relay Sudo account for that which was root causes of it. Thanks @Alexandre Ribeiro

Answer (score 0):

There is a Pull Request open in Cumulus with a fix to prevents the `StateDbError::TooManySiblingBlocks` error from being triggered.
https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1559

Not sure how you have arrived there, but in the meantime you have two options you can try:

- Follow this answer to revert the siblings: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3426/2762
- If you don't have data you want to preserve (you are testing), reset the blockchain state and process.
  To start over with a clean environment for testing, you should completely remove the chain state for the local relay chain nodes and the parachain.

  ```
  rm -rf /tmp/parachain
  rm -rf /tm/relay
  ```

And connect the parachain again: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/connect-a-local-parachain/

Comment: That's I have done already.